# Max Height Not Applied in Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, css-transitions

I am using checkboxes and labels to build an accordian menu. I have it working on andriod devices and in the most browsers when it is resized but for some reason it isn't working on Safari on desktop or iOS devices. Last Friday it was working and now it isn't, even though I can't find anything that would conflict. Here's the necessary code.

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' class='hide' name='custom_tailored' id='custom_tailored' />
<h1 class='dot-bor'><label for='custom_tailored'>Custom Solutions</label></h1>
<ul class='drawer'>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.drawer {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; /* plus vendor prefixes */
}
.hide:checked + .dot-bor + .drawer {
    max-height: 2500px;
}
```

As I said... this code works without any problems on all of the browsers if they're resized down to the right media query, as well as on andriod. When I plug my iPhone up to the computer and look through the console I can find where the CSS is getting applied (the max-height changes) but in the computed section it still shows `max-height: 0;`

**EDIT:**

I didn't realize it until today, but this problem is on Safari for Desktop as well. The weirdest part is that I can see in the inspector the max-height is being applied but computed still says `max-height: 0;` but then if I uncheck `max-height` and then check it again in the inspector suddenly the style gets applied.

The issue can be seen at [voicepad.com.mm-dev.net](http://voicepad.com.mm-dev.net) at a responsive browser size in safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://css-tricks.com/webkit-sibling-bug/) pointed me down the road towards a possible answer to my problem. My code is "working" but because of a bug with webkit, it wouldn't work (previously) on any webkit browser. Now apparently this was fixed but I'm thinking the bug is still out there. So I decided to try to skip out on the adjacent sibling selector `+` and just use the general sibling selector `~` (which is what changed between last friday when it was working on iOS and now when it isn't). The problem (and why I originally switched to adjacent selectors) is that I have more than one of these on each page. To remedy that, I am using a general selector along with the `:first-of-type` pseudo class to make sure I only get the first element in the list. In this case it happened to have the `.drawer.` class.

**tl;dr**

```
input.hide:checked ~ label.trigger ~ .drawer:first-of-type,
input.hide:checked ~ .dot-bor ~ .drawer:first-of-type {
    max-height: 2500px !important;
}
```

Comment: I'd just like to point out, that `:first-of-type` doesn't select based on the selector that comes before it (`.drawer`), but on the element type, i.e. which HTML tag is used.

Comment: @dalgard You have no idea how happy I am that I am not dealing with this client anymore. You're correct though that it doesn't work with the selector. Luckily in this instance it didn't matter since first-of-type and the first `.drawer` were the same.